# Why don't you [tʃʊ]

Tags: american-english, speech, ipa

What phonological processes take place in the pronunciation of [**Why don't you as** as just *[tʃʊ]*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gShUU_HKrqg)?

Comment: I've never heard such a pronunciation before, and the video you linked to appears to be private.

Comment: 'Palatalization'

Comment: @TannerSwett fixed the video is now public

Comment: The 'why' is _very_ understressed, but just discernable. Conversational deletion in progress?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth then it's [wai tʃʊ]? doesn't make sense yet

Comment: It's clipped (very clipped) diction. It's idiosyncratic. This actor's screen idiolect. I can't imagine Jeeves or Gandalf being so economical. Or many other people.

Comment: You can't end a word with a lax vowel like  [ʊ], the FOOT vowel. You mean [u], the GOOSE vowel. There may be some neutralization going on here, however.

Comment: @tchrist the guy has just clipped [wai doun], I do not think he cares about RP theoretical vowel space